# Should I always round the data before even trying defining and backtesting my trading strategy?

Tags: data, market-data, algorithmic-trading, historical-data

Newbie here, it happens that I have **8 months of OHLC price data set at 1 hour timeframe** from a particular cryptocurrency (ticket) called `ALICE`, here's a little sample of those:

[image: dataframe sample]

The first column above represent the timestamp of the open price, the next 4 columns represent the **OHLC** price values (set in USD), and the next to the next column represents the timestamp of the close price.

In this case, the last row in the dataframe above has the following **OHLC** values:

```
O = 7.56459843
H = 7.70936971
L = 7.45377539
C = 7.68385709
```

Now, if we look for the corresponding candle to that row in [this chart](https://www.binance.com/en/futures/ALICEUSDT) we get the following candle in the picture down below:

[image: chart sample]

And that candle has the following **OHLC** values:

```
O = 7.557
H = 7.709
L = 7.444
C = 7.681
```

So, as can be seen, the **OHLC** values I have do not exactly match with the **OHLC** values displayed in the chart.

So, I want to know if I just should round (up or down) every single **OHLC** value in my dataframe up to having 3 decimal points, before starting the definition and backtest of any trading strategy on this?

Or, should I actually work with the data as were delivered to me?

*Keep in mind that, obviously, when trying whatever strategy on live trading, the bot could only set prices up to 3 decimal points, so it would have to round the values anyway*

Comment: Rounding the data to three decimal points should not be a particularly big issue as long as you're not planning on scalping. In the end you can always observe how rounded prices changes the P&L of your strategy as opposed to using original prices. If the P&L's are practically the same, then your strategy is "robust" to rounding effects. If the P&L changes drastically, your strategy might do some "quick" trades to obtain a marginal profit after cost. Then rounding effects are an issue.

Comment: I see, I think my question has been answered, thanks @Pleb